# Unable to connect to SQL Server using the quarkus-hibernate-reactive due to incorrect reactive.url

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I had worked on Quarkus connecting to Postgres. But this is the first time I am trying to connect to SQL Server, which is the default server in my current project. I am following this [guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-reactive-panache) to create a database component.

The properties file contains the following:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mssql 
quarkus.datasource.username=<user-id>
quarkus.datasource.password=<pwd>

quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=sqlserver://localhost:1433/<db-name>?currentSchema=<schema-name>
quarkus.datasource.reactive.max-size=20 
hibernate.default_schema=<schema-name>
```

The application starts fine, but when I make a request to the Resource that internally uses the repository, I get the following error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> Error id f0a959d2-3201-4015-bfd7-6628ae9914d1-1, io.vertx.mssqlclient.MSSQLException: {number=208, state=1, severity=16, message='Invalid object name ''.', serverName='<sql-instance>', lineNumber=1, additional=[io.vertx.mssqlclient.MSSQLException: {number=8180, state=1, severity=16, message='Statement(s) could not be prepared.', serverName='<sql-instance>', lineNumber=1}]}

This means, my application is able to connect to the database, but it is not able to find the table. The table exists in a schema, and I am unable to pass the schema which may be the cause of the issue. If you check the properties file, I have tried with two options:

- Adding 'currentSchema' as a query param
- Adding the property 'hibernate.default_schema'

But none of the two options are working. There is no documentation on SQL Server that can help me provide the right configuration to the Quarkus application. Please help.

Comment: Does your database user has a default schema or has access to more than one schema? try with this property quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.default-schema      https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#quarkus-hibernate-orm_quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.default-schema

Comment: Thanks. It worked, but now we are facing another issue, https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client/issues/1000. This is said to be fixed in 4.1.2 version, but we have 4.1.4. Thanks for the hint. We managed to progress to the next stop.

Comment: I will post then this as an answer so you can accept it, and let other people know that it is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct property is `quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.default-schema` It is possible to check all the available configuration properties in this url https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#hibernate-configuration-properties